# How to compare two big files and get results to third file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have two files

1st file is like this:

```
www.example.com
www.domain.com
www.otherexample.com
www.other-domain.com
www.other-example.com
www.exa-ample.com
```

2nd file is like this (numbers after ;;; are between 0-10):

```
www.example.com;;;2
www.domain.com;;;5
www.other-domain;;;0
www.exa-ample.com;;;4
```

and i want compare these two files and output to third file like this:

```
www.otherexample.com
www.other-example.com
```

Both files have large size (over 500mb)

Comment: Can there also be domain names in the second file that is not present in the first? Or is it enough to output domains in the first that is not present in the second?

Answer (score 6):

Use `comm(1)` to compare two sorted files and to give the differences. Use `grep(1)` and `sort(1)` to get your files into an input format suitable for comparison with `comm`. Use *process substitution* in `bash` to tie it together:

```
comm -23 <(sort file1.txt) <(grep -o '^[^;]*' file2.txt | sort)
```

The `-23` argument to `comm` says to ignore lines that are common to both files (`-3`) and lines unique to file 2 (`-2`). Depending on your exact specification, you can use `-1`, `-2` or `-3`.

`grep -o '^[^;]*' file2.txt` just strips off everything after the first semicolon. You can use `sed(1)` for this, but if you are only extracting part of a line and not adding anything else, `grep` will often be faster.

`comm` needs the input files to be sorted, so `sort` is used to do that. The output will be sorted. `sort` uses locale specific collation, so you may need to set LC_ALL=C depending on the exact collation you want.

Note in your question you have www.other-domain in file 2, but www.other-domain.com in file 1. I have assumed that it is a typo in file 2 given the output.

This runs all the processes in parallel and streams the file data through them, so even if the files are large, it will not take up a lot of memory or any extra disk space to store temporary files.

Comment: On my system, it took `sed` 1/8th the time it took `grep`. `time sed 's/;.*//' filename >/dev/null` vs. `time grep -o '^[^;]*' filename > /dev/null` for a 900KB file with GNU `grep` 2.5.4 and GNU `sed` 4.2.1

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Interesting. In the past, I've had grep work a lot faster. Thanks for the data.

Comment: A lot depends on the data and other factors. I've had `grep 'foo' | awk '{...}'` be considerably faster than `awk '/foo/ {...}'` for a more complex "foo".

Answer (score 3):

If the input in `file2` contains a subset of the contents of `file1`, you could just

```
sed 's/;.*//' file2 | fgrep -vxf - file1 >not-in-file2
```

The same general idea can be applied to `diff` or `comm`.  However, `comm` requires sorted input, but if that is not a problem (or if your data can be sorted to start with), just preprocess the data from `file2`.

```
sed 's/;.*//' file2.sorted | comm -12 - file1.sorted >cmp.out
```

The constraint that input needs to be sorted is what allows `comm` to handle really large files, because it just needs to keep the latest data in memory at any one time.  You could do the same with your own custom `awk` script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$ diff file1 file2 > file3
```

But it seams to me you want to disregard `;;0` part, right?
Then you need to process it line by line stripping the last part, and, finally, comparing with `diff`

Comment: Re: "process it line by line stripping the last part": That can be done by replacing `file2` with `<(cut -d';' -f1 file2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [diff](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) command and direct the output to a 3 third file. E.g.,

```
% diff data1.txt data2.txt > diffs
```

The [diff man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff) shows a number of options that give you control over the comparison (processing and output).

The basic interactive operation without specifying an options, assuming you have the data you show in your post in files `data1.txt` and `data2.txt` yields:

```
% diff data1.txt data2.txt 

1,6d0
< www.example.com
< www.domain.com
< www.otherexample.com
< www.other-domain.com
< www.other-example.com
< www.exa-ample.com
```

Comment: with diff i get message: diff: memory exhausted

Comment: @MartinMocik Perhaps you can try `rdiff` according to this post: http://beerpla.net/2008/05/12/a-better-diff-or-what-to-do-when-gnu-diff-runs-out-of-memory-diff-memory-exhausted/

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is the file with the first content and `b` is the file with the second content:

```
while read line; do grep -q $line b || echo $line; done < a
```

It prints what is not found in the second file.

Comment: This will be *incredibly* slow for a set of files that are 500MB each.

Comment: sure, but it works. it's a good starting point for a simple C program